# How to get bash terminal to show grey auto-complete letters

Tags: terminal

So when I type commands and they exist in history then they are shown
In grey and I can auto-complete by using right arrow (for example)

Comment: Sounds like zsh command line autocompletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is provided by the Fish shell

https://fishshell.com/

"A command line shell for the 90's"